# Internal storage folder (0) not show any files

Tags: java, android

I am working on a video player app, I am showing video folders and videos,  this is working fine, But the Internal storage folder "0" did not show any files but I have around 15 video files, but the other folder working fine.

Here is my code

```
 private ArrayList<Videos_Models>LoadVideos(Context context, String FolderName){
        ArrayList<Videos_Models> TempList = new ArrayList<>();

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;



        String [] projection = {
                MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME


        };

        String selection = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA+" Like?";
        String  []selectionArgs = new String[]{"%" + FolderName +"%"};
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);

        if (cursor!= null){
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){

                try {
                String id =cursor.getString(0);
                String path =cursor.getString(1);
                String title =cursor.getString(2);
                String size =cursor.getString(3);
                String dateAdded =cursor.getString(4);
                String duration =cursor.getString(5);
                String fileName =cursor.getString(6);
                String bucket_name =cursor.getString(7);
                
                int durationa = Integer.parseInt(duration);

                String duration_formet;
                int sec = (durationa/1000)%60;
                int min = (durationa/(1000*60))%60;
                int hours = durationa/(1000*60*60);

                if (hours == 0){
                    duration_formet = String.valueOf(min).concat(":" .concat(String.format(Locale.UK, "%02d",sec)));
                }else {
                    duration_formet = String.valueOf(hours).concat(":" .concat(String.format(Locale.UK, "%02d",min).concat(":" .concat(String.format(Locale.UK, "%02d",sec)))));

                }

                Videos_Models videoFiles = new Videos_Models(id, path, title,fileName,size, dateAdded,duration_formet);

                Log.d("path", path);


               if (FolderName.endsWith(bucket_name)){
                  TempList.add(videoFiles);
               }

            }catch (Exception e){

                }

            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        return TempList;
    }
```

What I am doing wrong ? and how to fix this?

Comment: Check your `catch (Exception e)`, it's probably because you are trying to access the data column.

Comment: Please name full path. It is probably `/storage/emulated/0`.

Comment: Nowhere in your code you use "0".

Comment: blackapps "0" mean internal storage folder, please check the screenshot.        https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xSVzkcyUj7asSvtdC08_RhRo19GGOlUj/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you have this permission
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

In your manifest file.

Comment: still i am getting same, INTERNAL_STORAGE folder does'mt show any files.

Comment: you can see screenshot     https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xSVzkcyUj7asSvtdC08_RhRo19GGOlUj/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Since what you need is the internal storage
Can you try to replace your `Uri uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;`
with
`uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;`
see there is a difference

Comment: I replace "URI" but still getting the same.